# Vista Business can't contact domain controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-vista, login, domain-controller

One of laptops in our firm has problems contacting domain controller. It is Vista Business with DHCP enabled config (DNS set up correctly). At this point only one person can login and only if network cable isn't connected. Noone else can login, including domain admin - no matter if cable is or isn't connected.

Vista spits out a message in local language, so here is an attempt to translate it back to English:

*Secure relationship between workstation and PDC couldn't be establish ?*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a problem with the workstation account.

I'd try dropping the machine off the domain and back into a workgroup. Delete the workstation account, and then add the machine back to the domain.

Comment: True... Something went wrong there. I took laptop from domain, deleted account in AD and then rejoined machine back to domain. Seems it's happy now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the network settings. Are you getting a valid IP address? If not, check the network adapter: drivers, network speed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds to me like the machine password expired and due to a time synch issue or something of that nature its unable to negotiate an update with the DC so it isnt letting you log in.

Can you ping the domain by name(e.g. "ping domain.local") or ping the ip address of any of the domain controllers once logged in using the one user that works?  If not there might be a networking issue like Randolph suggested.

If you are able to ping a DC, you might want to try this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325850